# How to correctly hide/show the navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with some viewControllers. Only one `viewController` must not display the `navigationBar`, so in this controller I have:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true,animated:true)
}
```

Now, I noticed that this is a *global* setting because anytime I access another `viewController` the navigation bar is hidden.

So, in every `viewController`, in my `viewWillAppear`, I will make it visible again.

But, is this the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the navigationBar to hidden in the viewWillAppear and to visible in the viewWillDisappear of this **one** viewController like that:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true,animated:true)
}


override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false,animated:true)
}
```

Comment: Any opinions how this compares to the self.myNavigationBar.hidden = true/false, for UIViewControllers that have had the navigation bar added as extra?

Comment: You can also use your version and set the property. I think this is only a design question, which has to be decided on your own. I used the function because it was addressed in the question and therefore didn't want to confuse someone.

Answer (score 0):

In your UIViewController, if you are using a referencing outlet for the UINavigationBar, then you can change the state via the 'hidden' property, where myNavigationBar is the IBOutlet you defined:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.myNavigationBar.hidden = true
}
```

Edit: seeing marc's answer, I am curious to know whether the property or the function is the preferred way to go?

Comment: This is interesting too, thanks. You should ask mark14 for the preferred way. Sometimes, I feel a little lost because it looks like there are many ways to reach the same goals